# Why doesn't Grunt generate ports to use?

Tags: localhost, gruntjs, port, grunt-contrib-watch

I am sure there is some simple reason I am missing. I would like to run multiple builds of different projects at the same time. Each project is looking for a port and each live reload is looking for a port. Why not set it up to generate a port between a range and if that port is in use try again? Would it be acceptable for me to try and write something to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it is up to the individual task to determine the port and then most of the time provide an option to configure the port.

For `grunt-contrib-watch`, the default port of the live reload server is `35729` to align with other tools that also use that port. But the port can be overridden with `options: { livereload: 1337 }`.

To have the port be dynamically set based on a range, you would need to build a mechanism to determine the port and set it within the config, ie:

```
grunt.config('watch.options.livereload', determineWhichPort())
```

There is an existing Grunt task for finding open ports called grunt-openport: https://github.com/shama/grunt-openport

You can configure the port to use an open port within a range by having the task `openport` run before the other tasks. Here is an example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    options: {
      livereload: true,
    },
    all: {
      files: ['src/*.js'],
      tasks: ['copy'],
    },
  },
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-openport');
grunt.registerTask('default', [
  'openport:watch.options.livereload:35729:40000',
  'watch'
]);
```

Now running `grunt` will find the next open port between `35729-40000` and then run the watch task with that port.

This can be used with any other task that enables the port to be configured by changing `watch.options.livereload` to point to the desired place in the config.